# How to delete a certain field in an array inside Meteor collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, meteor

I can't delete a field inside an array in Meteor collection. Here is the structure of my collection:

[image: collection structure]

I have tried this:

```
SMUProfiles.update({
  owner: this.userId,
      'classrooms.owner': classroom_id,
    }, {
      $pull: {
          'classroom.$.owner': classroom_id 
      }
    }
 )
```

but unsuccessful.

I want to delete any of the key under 'owner' array, and I only have reference to its value, and not their index. In this case, I have a reference to `6Yi64LqpqnfsHv4ms` as `classroom_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try

```
SMUProfiles.update({
  owner: this.userId,
}, {
    $pull: {
      'classrooms.owner': classroom_id
    }
  }
)
```

I think simple pull operator with object path should be enough to pull elements from array.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's no easy way to do that currently. So, for the benefit of others who might be looking at a similar problem, here's my solution:

```
//** Method for deleting Classroom */
'classroom.delete'(classroom_id){
    if(!this.userId){
            throw new Meteor.Error('not-authorised');
        }
    Classrooms.remove(classroom_id)

    let classids = Classrooms.find({ owner: this.userId 
}).fetch().map(function(classrooms){
      return classrooms._id })
      //console.log(classids);
      SMUProfiles.update({
        owner: this.userId,
      }, {
        $set: {
          'classrooms.owner': classids
        }
      }
    )
  },
```

The story behind this solution:
I have 2 collections `Classrooms` and `SMUProfiles`. Upon registration, a new record will be created under SMUProfile for that user, containing several other details (refer to the picture attached in the question above), including a record of the classroom ids that user has created.

Now, when the user delete a classroom in `Classrooms` collection, i need to also delete the id of the classroom that has been deleted, in `SMUProfile`. I was originally trying to delete the id from the array of ids in `SMUProfile` but was not successful.

I solved this by re-reading the `Classrooms` collection after a classroom has been deleted, re-iterate the ids of the remaining classrooms inside an array, and `$set` that new array of classrooms ids to `SMUProfile`.